# change href jquery

Tags: jquery

On a search results page I have links. I would like to change the href of certain href from `DispForm.aspx?ID=n` to `AllItems.aspx?ID=n` but just for the href that have `/R/I/P/` in the url.

I would like to use jQuery to change those href.
Any suggestions?

```
<a title="" href="http://win/R/I/P/IL/F/DispForm.aspx?ID=n" id="S">link one</a>
<a title="" href="http://win/R/I/P/L/PN/DispForm.aspx?ID=n" id="S">link two</a>
<a title="" href="http://win/L/L/DispForm.aspx?ID=n" id="S">link three</a>
```

Comment: Firstly, you should not use the same ID for multiple elements. Try with class instead.

Comment: Ids should be always unique , you should never duplicate them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this:

```
$("a[href*='/R/I/P/']").each(function(){
   var href = $(this).attr('href').replace('DispForm.aspx?', 'AllItems.aspx?');
   $(this).attr("href", href);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
jQuery('a[href*="/R/I/P/"]').each(function(){
    this.href = this.href.replace('DispForm', 'AllItems');
});
```

Comment: @user472285 What do you mean "too"? Check the timestamps on the answers

Answer (score 0):

this should do it!

http://jsfiddle.net/2VZMb/

Comment: this looks promising but i would like to keep the ?ID=n at the end of the href

Comment: And you have to do this through javascript? don't serverside already know the ID?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function() {
var href = $(this).attr('href');
if (href.indexOf("/R/I/P") >= 0) {
  $(this).attr('href', new_href);
}
```